# Pythonic way to find any item from a list within a string

Tags: python, string, list, search

The problem is simple enough. I'm writing a function which returns true if the string contains any of the illegal names.

line is a string.

illegal_names is an iterable.

```
def has_illegal_item(line, illegal_names):
    illegal_items_found = False
    for item in illegal_names:
        if item in line:
            illegal_items_found = True
            break
    return illegal_items_found
```

So this works fine, but it seems a bit clumsy and long-winded. Can anyone suggest a neater and more pythonic way to write this? Could I use a list comprehension or regex?

Comment: Unless you know something about the string or illegal names (eg. whitespace separated tokens) I don't think you can use list comprehension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
any(name in line for name in illegal_names)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I even used the word any in my question's title, so perhaps I should've found this.

Comment: The only caveat about simply using `in` is that it's a substring test, not a word test: `"Robert" in "Sarah Robertson"` is True.  But that may be what you wanted anyway.

Comment: @DSM: true. It's easy enough to turn it into a baseline word check: `any(name in re.findall(r"\w+", line) for name in illegal_name)`. Word splitting can be an NLP-complete problem, though.

Comment: Thanks DSM, I expected that behaviour and it is what I want. I'm setting the list of illegal names as a constant, so I can add whitespaces manually as required.

Answer (score 1):

let's have a look on following sample:

```
line = "This is my sample line with an illegal item: FOO"
illegal_names = ['FOO', 'BAR']
```

and you want now to find out whether your `line` contains one of the illegal names, then you do this with the widespread [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) and a length check:

```
is_correct = not bool(len([ hit for hit in illegal_names if hit in line ]))
# or
is_correct = len([ hit for hit in illegal_names if hit in line ]) == 0
```

Pretty easy, short and in relation to other `lambda` version easy to read and unterstand.

-Colin-

Answer (score 0):

I go with @larsmans solution, but there another ways of doing it.

```
def check_names(line, names):
    #names should be set
    parsed_line = set(line.replace(',', '').split())
    return bool(parsed_line.intersection(names))
```

This can also be written using `lambda`

```
In [57]: x = lambda line, names: bool(set(line.replace(",", "").split()).intersection(names))

In [58]: x("python runs in linux", set(["python"]))
Out[58]: True
```

lamdba version can be overkill of readability

Comment: Ah intersection - interesting, but more complicated.

Comment: @JamesBradbury: not complicated but different way to see the same  problem.